# MongoDB sort deeply nested arrays during $map

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id":1,
  "title":"a new board title",
  "lists":[
    {
      "_id":1,
      "title":"dasads",
      "position":"c",
      "cards":[{ id: 1, list_id: 1, title: "a card" }]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting this structure by mapping over the lists in the $project aggregation stage:

```
{
      '$map' => {
        input: "$lists",
        as: "list",
        in: {
          '$mergeObjects' => [
            "$$list",
            {
              cards: {
                '$filter' => {
                  input: "$cards",
                  cond: {
                    '$eq' => ["$$this.list_id", "$$list._id"]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

However, I want to sort the lists array, and each card array based on their title alphabetically. How can I do this?

Also, can I do the sorting during the map stage im already doing, instead of unwinding again for better performance?

Comment: Apply $sort earlier in the pipeline?

Comment: @D.SM The thing is, cards are sorted within their individual list.

Comment: Maybe add some code to illustrate what is happening and what you want.